Proof regarding $ \sum\vec T_i\cdot \vec a_i=0$ this relation for a pulley mass system
How to prove that for a system containing more than one pulley and more than two masses this relation will hold.
$$ \sum\vec T_i\cdot \vec a_i=0$$ where $T_i$ and is the tension acting  on the $i^{th}$ body of mass $m_i$ and $a_i$ is the acc$^n$ of that body. I was able to prove it for a three body-two pulley system but couldn't prove it for a $n$-body system as a general case.

$\def \b {\mathbf}$
From the FBD the  Newton EOM's are
$$\b M\,\b a=\b F+\underbrace{\b C_C^T\,\b \lambda}_{\b T}\tag 1$$
and the constraint equations for pulley system
$$ \b C_C\,\b a=\b 0 \tag 2$$
where $~\b \lambda~$ is the generalized tension vector $~\b F~$ external force .
the constraint matrix $~\b C_C~$ is for pulley system constant (ones or zeros)
transformed equation (1) and (2) to the generalized coordinates $~\b a_q~$ $~a\mapsto \b J\,\b a_q~$ where the Jacobian matrix $\b J~$ constant .
$$\b M\,\b J\,\b a_q=\b F+\b C_C^T\,\b \lambda\tag 3$$
$$\b C_C\,\b J\,\b a_q=\b 0\tag 4$$
from the D'Alembert principle  $~\b J^T\,\b C_C^T\,\b \lambda=\b 0~$ thus
$$\underbrace{\left(\b C_C^T\,\b \lambda\right)^T}_{\b T^T} ~\underbrace{\b J\,\b a_q}_{\b a}=\b 0$$
Example

Newton equation
$$m_1\,a_1=-m_1\,g+\lambda_1\\
m_2\,a_2=-m_2\,g-\lambda_1+\lambda_2\\
m_3\,a_3=-m_3\,g-\lambda_2$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$\b C_C^T= \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  -1 & 1 \\
  0 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
equation (2) $~\b C_C\,\b a=\b 0$
$$   \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&-1&0\\ 0&1&-1
\end {array} \right]
 \,
\begin{bmatrix}
  a_1 \\
  a_2 \\
  a_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
                0 \\
                0 \\
              \end{bmatrix}$$
with $~a_1~$ the generalized coordinate
$$\b J=\left[ \begin {array}{c} 1\\ 1
\\ 1\end {array} \right] 
$$
$~\b C_C\,\b J~$
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & -1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & -1 \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   1 \\
   1 \\
   1 \\
 \end{bmatrix}=
 \begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$
